# converting xsl-fo to pdf middle dot encoding is not recognized

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I am looking for a way to print a list with middle dot.
I am using an xsl file to convert it in a pdf file. 
Below is a sample of my xsl file which lead to an unrecognized middle dot in my pdf file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Calibri" >
<fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="FirstPage" margin-top="0.5cm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="6cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm" />
            <fo:region-before extent="1cm" region-name="first-page-header"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="1cm" region-name="first-page-footer" padding-left="1cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:inline font-family="Symbol">&#183;</fo:inline>
    </fo:block>    
</fo:flow>
```

I have tried to include this symbol with "&#183", "&#xb7" and "& middot" but it does not succed.

I also tried to add **encoding-mode="single-byte"** next to **font-family="Calibri"** but still no success.

Any idea why it does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `font-family="Symbol"`.  At present, you are using the Symbol font for the `&#xb7;` and not using Calibri, so changing the configuration for Calibri isn't going to change anything.

According to 'Character Map' on Windows 7, Symbol does not have a character at 0xB7 and Calibri has Middle Dot at 0xB7.

(If the purpose of the `fo:inline` is just to change the font, then you can also drop the `fo:inline`.)